# This compiles, but it doesn't run. Any ideas?

Tags: c++

This program will compile but it will not run. Every time it runs I receive this:

"Unhandled exception at 0x00D761EE in Assignment3.1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//Function Prototype
void getSize(int *);
float *getValues(int *);
float getMax(const float *, const int *);


int main()
{
    float * ptData = nullptr;
    int * ptr = nullptr;
    int num;
    getSize(&num);
    float values = *getValues(&num);
    float max = getMax(ptData, &num);

    return 0;
}

//*******************************************************************************************************
void getSize(int * ptr)
{
    cout << "Please enter a size to the array: ";
    cin >> *ptr;
    while (*ptr <= 1)
    {
        cout << "!!!Error: an array's size cannot be less than or equal to 1!\n";
        cout << "Please enter a size to the array: ";
        cin >> *ptr;
    }
}

//*******************************************************************************************************

float * getValues(int * ptr)
{
    float * ptData = new float[*ptr];

    cout << "Please enter all values of the array: \n";
    for (int count = 0; count < *ptr; count++)
    {
        cout << "Value " << (count + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> ptData[count];
    }

    delete[] ptData;
    ptData = 0;

    return ptData;
}

//*******************************************************************************************************

float getMax(const float * ptData, const int * ptr)
{
    float highest;
    highest = *ptData;
    for (int count = 1; count < *ptr; count++)
    {
        if (ptData[count] > highest)
            highest = ptData[count];
    }

    return highest;
}
```

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* -- For one, refusing to use `std::vector` instead of pointers.

Comment: For two, failing to step through in the debugger to locate the problem and determine the cause. An address of 0x00000000 means accessing a nul pointer. Using the debugger would help you identify where and what specifically was nul. If you haven't learned to use that debugger, now is the perfect time to start learning.

Comment: *Assignment3* -- If this really is an assignment given to you for a C++ course, run away from this.  No one writes C++ programs this way.

Answer (score 1):

There are few misconceptions in your code:

First, you don't have to pass value by address to change it in C++, you can pass it by reference, so changing `void getSize(int *);` to  `void getSize(int &);` will be better (if you don't know references, find some basic guide on C++).

Moreover, it doesn't really make sense to have function returning `void` when all it does is giving you `int` value. Either rewrite it to `int getSize()` or pass some meaningful information, like error code (`int getSize(int &);`) or if function succeeded  (e.g. `bool getSize(int &);` will return true when getting value succeeded).

Secondly, `float *getValues(int *);` means that `getValues` returns pointer to float (possibly holding an array, given the name of function). This functions doesn't have to take it's argument by address, because it doesn't change it, so `float *getValues(int);` looks better (this is also the case for `getMax` function).

In C++ we don't really use raw pointers, we have stl for containers, like `std::vector`, which can easily replace `float *` array. So the best signature for function `getValues` would be `std::vector<float> getValues(int);` or if you want to pass specific information why fetching values failed, you can have `int getValues(int, std::vector<fload> &);`.

Thirdly, writing `float values = *getValues(&num);` doesn't make sense, I'm pretty sure compilator should complain about it. Probably the asterisk `*` got here, because you don't quite understand what `float *getValues(int *);` means. `*` doesn't belong to function name it's part of specifying return type, so it shouldn't be used when function is called.

One more thing:

```
float * ptData = new float[*ptr];

...

delete[] ptData;
ptData = 0;

return ptData;
```

it will destroy all the data you've fetched from user and `getValues` will return null pointer. `pData` should be deleted only after you don't need it anymore, so in your case it should be after calling `getMax`.

Answer (score -1):

access violation means your writing on the memory that is not yours. so you must debug your code and see where that is taking place.
I edited your code and now it works perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//Function Prototype
void getSize(int *);
float *getValues(int *);
float getMax(const float *, const int *);


int main()
{
   /* float * ptData = nullptr;*/
    int * ptr = nullptr;
    int num;
    getSize(&num);
    float *values = getValues(&num);
    float max = getMax(values, &num);


    cout << max << endl;
    return 0;
}

//*******************************************************************************************************
void getSize(int * ptr)
{
    cout << "Please enter a size to the array: ";
    cin >> *ptr;
    while (*ptr <= 1)
    {
        cout << "!!!Error: an array's size cannot be less than or equal to 1!\n";
        cout << "Please enter a size to the array: ";
        cin >> *ptr;
    }
}

//*******************************************************************************************************

float * getValues(int * ptr)
{
    float * ptData = new float[*ptr];

    cout << "Please enter all values of the array: \n";
    for (int count = 0; count < *ptr; count++)
    {
        cout << "Value " << (count + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> ptData[count];
    }

 /*   delete[] ptData;
    ptData = 0;*/

    return ptData;
}

//*******************************************************************************************************

float getMax(const float * ptData, const int * ptr)
{
    float highest = ptData[0];
    for (int count = 0; count < *ptr; count++)
    {
        if (ptData[count] > highest)
            highest = ptData[count];
    }

    return highest;
}
```

but I say that you could write this code in a better way, without using pointers.

Comment: SO is not for rewriting code for OP, but for explaining what is a problem and giving a hint on how to solve it, not giving out whole solution.